# Silicone/glass material

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, glass

Hello blender wizards,

I need help creating this kind of rendering with silicone shader looking like this:

[image]

Clearly this is not physical based material and it needs to use some trickery to make it look this clear. Do you have any ideas how do they managed to achieve that mockups look?

Comment: what is your current result and setup?

Comment: hmm, probably glass material with glossy shader to make it more shiny, It's clear to see through so no roughness, maybe little clearcoat rouhnes... This page shows that IOR for Glass, Fused Silica is 1.459  ( https://pixelandpoly.com/ior.html )

Answer (score 2):

You could try a mix between *Glossy* and *Transparent* with an *(Input) Layer Weight (Facing)* as factor, and keep the *Roughness* of the *Glossy* rather low:

[image]